# Disable days in a datepicker using select statement to database table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datepicker

first code is for take dates between 2 dates from  my table `reservas`...

```
<?php
include "controlreservas/conexion.php";
$sql1="select llegada, salida from reservas";
$query = $con->query($sql1);
$r=$query->fetch_array();
$begin = new DateTime( $r["llegada"] );
$end = new DateTime( $r["salida"] );
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
?>
<?php foreach ($daterange as $date) : ?>
<?php echo $date->format("Y-m-d"); ?>
```

this it´s working :

```
2016-12-20
2016-12-21
2016-12-22
2016-12-23
2016-12-24
```

Now the next code is for disable this dates (all this dates, only get from the select ) in my datepicker :

```
<script>
$(function() {
var disabledDays = ["<?php echo $date->format("Y-m-d"); ?>"];
var date = new Date();
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    $( "#datepicker1").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
            for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
                if($.inArray(y + '-' + (m+1) + '-' + d,disabledDays) != -1) {
                    //return [false];
                    return [true, 'ui-state-active', ''];
                }
            }
            return [true];

        }
    });
});
    });
</script>
```

the result is only disables first date, not all dates : [image: only disable day 2016-12-20]

thanks for you time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `disabledDates` (in javascript) should be an `Array` of `strings`, where each string represents a date that you want to disable.

What you can do is create that list from the `$daterange` variable that you have in php:

```
$dates_ar = [];
foreach ($daterange as $date) {
    $dates_ar[] = $date->format("Y-m-d");
}
$disabled_dates = '"' . implode('", "', $dates_ar) .'"';
```

And then in your `javascript` code you can use the `$disabled_dates` variable (which is a string that contains the values you need:

```
$(function() {
    var disabledDays = [<?php echo $disabled_dates; ?>];
```

Comment: Thanks you! with this it´s working :D:D  (in the part   $dates_ar[] = date->format("Y-m-d"); i put  $ before date ..$date and ok ).

Comment: Not sure I follow... what?

Comment: Hello..sorry but you know how is when :  $sql1="select llegada, salida from reservas where id_habitacion='$id_habitacion'"; ? I put this and it´s working BUT only show the first registry for example reservas have 2 reservas in the same id_habitacion and the datepicker only showme the first , you know how resolve this?

Comment: You should fetch all the values and put all of them in the disabled (not only the first).

Comment: yes.. this code not is for fetch? $query = $con->query($sql1);
$r=$query->fetch_array();  $begin = new DateTime( $r["llegada"] );
$end = new DateTime( $r["salida"] ); , i don´know what is bad

Comment: I think it's better to open a new question with all the information (the relevnt block-code). It's hard to understand the code in the comments;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204960/disables-all-dates-in-datepicker-where-id-id Here is