# Disables all dates in datepicker where id =$id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

Hello I have first this form  :
agregareserva.php:

```
    <form action="GUImostrarcalendario.php" method="post" name="a">
    <select  type="text" id="id_habitacion"  name="id_habitacion" />
    <option value"1">ID 1</option>
    <option value="2">ID 2</option></select>
    <input type="submit" name="a"  value="Ver"/>
    </form>
```

In GUImostrarcalendario.php I have :

```
<?php
    include "controlreservas/conexion.php";
    $id_habitacion=$_POST["id_habitacion"];
    $sql1="SELECT llegada,salida,id_reserva FROM reservas 
    where id_habitacion ='$id_habitacion'";
    $query = $con->query($sql1);
    ?>
    <?php if($query->num_rows>0):?>
    <?php while ($r=$query->fetch_array()):?>
    <?php

    $begin = new DateTime( $r["llegada"] );
    $end = new DateTime( $r["salida"] );
    $end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
    $dates_ar = [];
    foreach ($daterange as $date) {
        $dates_ar[] = $date->format("Y-m-d");
    }
    $disabled_dates = '"' . implode('", "', $dates_ar) .'"';
    ?>
    <script>
    $(function() {
    var disabledDays = [<?php echo $disabled_dates; ?>];
    var date = new Date();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
        $( "#datepicker9").datepicker({ 
            dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
                for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
                    if($.inArray(y + '-' + (m+1) + '-' + d,disabledDays) != -1) {
                        //return [false];
                        return [true, 'ui-state-active', ''];
                    }
                }
                return [true];

            }
        });
    });
    });

    </script>

    <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php else:?>
    <?php endif;?>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker9" name ="datepicker9"/>
```

This code is for show in the datepicker all dates in booking(reservas), when id_habitacion (id room) is select in the input select.

This code is working but only show in the datepicker the first record in the database, for example the table where id_habitacion= 1 is :

[image]

i'ts all dates in booking for this id

And my code result in datepicker:

[image]

Show only one booking date

Finally I need the datepicker show all dates how in the table I show.

Thankss.

Comment: `.....code javascript ..` ... erm, no javascript in your code at all - in fact, that code looks incomplete, and there's no indication of how that code impacts the rendered web page at all

Comment: Please show sample of expected html . Really not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Also makes no sense generating the same javascript over and over inside a while loop and not generating any associated html

Comment: you're also running `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` inside a `$(function() {` which is redundant as `$(function() {` is exactly the same as `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` - so the document is already ready, doesn't need to be ready again

Comment: In short, broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation of what this UI is supposed to look like and do

Comment: your javascript output would very likely look like this - https://jsfiddle.net/j8s0eLx4/ - does that look right to you? (the order of the duplicated blocks is not necessarily as shown, as you have no `order by` in the SQL statement, the order could very well be reversed - only by looking at the source code of the page in the browser would you be able to determine which order those blocks are in - either way, having that code like that looks wrong, as the datepicker beforeShowDay callback is likely to be incorrect

Comment: seems to me, you want your code to look more like http://pastebin.com/NC1DfqWA (note - I use the C-like `while() {...}` rather than `while(): ... endwhile;` )

Comment: I also combined those consecutive `<?php ... ?>` because your code is less readable with `<?php if ... ?><?php while ...?>` etc

Comment: So it seems all you need is to pass disabled dates to one datepicker, then think of the php only creating an array of dates and you can pass that **final array** to the datepicker by using `var disabledDays =<?php echo json_encode($date_arr)?>` and you don't need to manually `implode()` the array either. But this is outside the loop as @JaromandaX is showing you

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I know my code is not much readable , sorry for this and ty , I going to  proof your link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code currently creates multiple instances of

```
`$( "#datepicker9").datepicker({`
```

One for each date range. You need to change your code to only do this once - so, outside of the while loop

This requires $date_ar be defined outside of the wile loop as well

Also, you are using consecutive php fragments of code unnecessarily

The code should look like this

```
<?php
    include "controlreservas/conexion.php";
    $id_habitacion=$_POST["id_habitacion"];
    $sql1="SELECT llegada,salida,id_reserva FROM reservas where id_habitacion ='$id_habitacion'";
    $query = $con->query($sql1);
    $dates_ar = [];
    if($query->num_rows>0) {
        while ($r=$query->fetch_array()) {
            $begin = new DateTime( $r["llegada"] );
            $end = new DateTime( $r["salida"] );
            $end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 
            $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
            $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
            foreach ($daterange as $date) {
                $dates_ar[] = $date->format("Y-m-d");
            }
        }
        ?>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                var disabledDays = <?php echo json_encode($date_arr)?>;
                var date = new Date();
                $( "#datepicker9").datepicker({ 
                    dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
                    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                        var m = date.getMonth() + 1, 
                            d = date.getDate(), 
                            y = date.getFullYear(),
                            strdate = [y,m,d].join('-');
                        if (disabledDays.indexOf(strdate) == -1) {
                            return [true, 'ui-state-active', ''];
                        }
                        return [false];
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
?>
<input type="text" id="datepicker9" name ="datepicker9"/>
```

This include @charlietfl's excellent point about not using implode, but using

```
var disabledDays = <?php echo json_encode($date_arr)?>;
```

instead

Note, I've used the "C" coding style

```
if() {
    while() {
    }
}
```

rather than the alternate style you used

```
if():
    while():
    endwhile;
else:
endif;
```

Also, no `else` block since there's nothing to do anyway

Comment: edit : <?php echo json_encode($date_arr)?>  by $dates_ar) I edited this and I change:  return [true, 'ui-state-active', '']; by return [true, '', ''];   and it´s perfect very perfect I try this how 4 days thanks thanks  :D:D and @charlietfl ty too :D

Comment: you know why dates from 2017 not are disable? I add row     with year 2017 and this dates are not disables

Comment: Look at the source code in the browser - see if the data in `var disabledDays` looks correct